# Android Array for aChartengine

Tags: android, arrays, graph, double, achartengine

I'm trying to display the result of a query in a bar graph using the library aChartengine. To view all the data taken before I put them in an ArrayList, but then as I enter the double array in the for loop? This is what I have so far.

```
private void grafico(String years){
   SQLiteDatabase db = new ReHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
   ArrayList <Double> dettagli = new ArrayList<Double>();
   String sql ="SELECT number FROM Table GROUP BY motion";

   Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
   while (c.moveToNext()){
      double number= c.getDouble(0);
      dettagli.add(number);

      XYSeries eeSeries = new XYSeries("series");
      for(int i=0;i<...;i++){           
         eeSeries.add(i);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you should do something like this:

Fetch your data:

```
XYSeries eeSeries = new XYSeries("series");

int i = 0;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
while (c.moveToNext()){
  double number= c.getDouble(0);
  eeSeries.add(i++, number);
}
c.close();
```

Prepare your Graph/renderer:

```
// Create a dataset to hold each series
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
// Add the series to the dataset
dataset.addSeries(eeseries);

// Creating XYSeriesRenderer
XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
renderer.setFillPoints(true);
renderer.setLineWidth(2);
renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

// Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Title");

multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
```

The simplest way to show your graph  is to use ChartFactory:

```
Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(
    getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: do not look at the brackets, because the method does not end at that point. My problem is in the Loop. –

Comment: Don't worry, I'don't look at brackets, please see if the loop is what you want..if I understand your question.